# Windows Phone 10 Captive Browser to Full Browser

Tags: html, browser

I have a captive portal which opens whenever you are connected in a network, and there are videos in it. The captive browser in windows doesn't allow to play the videos embeded in html5.

Is there any way to customize my `<a></a>` tag to open the full browser while in the captive browser?

Or is there a way to play a video in a captive browser in Windows Phone 10.

Answer (score 0):

No. This is the choice of the user, not the web site.

Comment: there's no way to make a link to execute the full browser?

Comment: @RavAngelo You are asking to take control of the user's software. No right minded manufacturer of a cell phone, even Microsoft, is going to let you do that and no right-thinking person would buy a phone that would let you do that. Worse, you are asking if a software program, the browser, has code that can let you control the user's phone.